# How to use dynamic method names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a dictionary with method names of my classes, when I call an other class I pass an identifier, which in turn can get the method name from a dictionary.

```
>>> class test():
...     def __init__(self):
...             pass
...     def pstuff (self):
...             print ("print some text")
... 
>>> blah = test()
>>> blah.pstuff()
print some text
>>> pff = "blah"
>>> pff.pstuff()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: **1st:** not python 3 (print is a _function_), **2nd:** does not work that way, **3rd:** whats your specific problem? **4th:** where is your stacktrace/error message? **5th:** did you research putting functions into dicts? **6th:** where is your dict defined - there is no dict in your [mre] - please read [ask] and [edit] your question

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `globals()` dictionary which holds your variables' names as keys and their referenced object as the value. So you could do:

```py
>>> blah = test()
>>> blah.pstuff()
print some text
>>> pff = "blah"
>>> blah2 = globals()[pff]
>>> blah2.pstuff()
print some text
```